# Javascript innerText nuance

Tags: javascript, innertext

I'm wondering about the innerText property. Consider the following markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div>
         <div>foo</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <div>
         <div>bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, lets run the following code:

**JS**

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass');
//var a = document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass div div');
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    console.log(a[i].innerText);
    if (a[i].innerText == "foo"){
        console.log("found");
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3149ha75/)

Running this code as is, outputs `foo`, and empty line, and then `bar`.

If I comment out the first line of the script, and uncomment the second one which then closes-in on the exact level of the divs containing the text, this code outputs `foo`, `found`, `bar`.

My question here is: If on the first iteration the script outputs `foo`, how come `a[i].innerText == "foo"` isn't `true`? Oh, and where is that empty line comming from?

Comment: i have no idea why that `\n` is appearing, but better to use `textContent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since myClass has 2 div inside of itself, javascript see them as a line "\n" and hence "foo" doesn't equal "foo\n"

But if we change the code like that:

```
 if (a[i].innerText == "foo\n"){
        console.log("found");
 }
```

Then you can see found log in the console.
http://jsfiddle.net/3149ha75/5/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Halil Bilgin's answer you can `trim` the inner text to remove the `\n`

In this example I've used `jQuery.trim()`:

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    console.log(a[i].innerText);
    if (jQuery.trim(a[i].innerText) == "foo"){
        $("pre").text("found:"+a[i].innerText);
        console.log("found");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82L9g868/2/